# Unity3d game packaging service

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Please, I heard that Ubuntu provides service to package Unity3d games, is it still true and where can I find info about it?

Thank you, Marek.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a paid app (or game in this case) developed in Unity3D you can submit it via the "MyApps" website. Canonical have people who can assist with the packaging of your game once submitted.

https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/